# excluir datos en mi busqueda sql

Tags: php, sql

Poseo una función que me hace una busqueda en mi base de datos
trabajo con mysql

```
function listUser($conexion){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

ella me esta retornando todos los valores hechos con la unión de todas las tablas pero necesito excluir el p.id = u.id_persona del usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui despliego la lista de los nombres de la lista

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['usuario'])): ?>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
             <select name="destinatario" id="destinatario">
                <option value="0" selected>Seleccione</option>
                <?php while($resultado  = $consulta2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
                  <option value="<?=$resultado['idUsuario']?>">
                    <?php echo $resultado['personaNombre'] ?>
                    <?php echo $resultado['apellido'] ?>
                    <?php if ($resultado['id_cede'] = 11)
                        $resultado['id_cede'] = "Sistemas";
                     echo $resultado['id_cede'] ?>
                  </option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
              </select>
              <label for="destinatario">Destinatario</label>
            </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

y aqui el muestro el nombre de mi usuario actual

```
<div class="col s6">
              <strong><?=$resultado['personaNombre']?> <?=$resultado['apellido']?></strong>
            </div>
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo donde despliegas el nombre.

Comment: añadido @alanfcm

Comment: Me referia al primer nombre en la parte de arriba, el que no quieres que aparezca en la consulta.

Comment: corregido @alanfcm

Answer (score 2):

Puedes condicionar tu query pasando a la función como parámetro el id del usuario a excluir y usando el `WHERE` en el sql ej:

```
function listUser($conexion, $excludeId = null){

    $whereCondition = '';
    if ($excludeId) {
        $whereCondition = " WHERE p.id != $excludeId";
    }

    $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                          FROM persona as p
                                          JOIN usuario as u
                                          on p.id = u.id_persona
                                          JOIN departamento as d
                                          on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                          $whereCondition -- agrega ésta condición
                                          ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

P.D.: Modificado para que el `$excludeId` sea opcional en caso que necesites usar la misma función en otro lugar para listar a todos los usuarios

Te dejo la versión pensada para que siempre excluyas un id de usuario (se elimina el if del código anterior):

```php
function listUser($conexion, $excludeId){

$consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                      FROM persona as p
                                      JOIN usuario as u
                                      on p.id = u.id_persona
                                      JOIN departamento as d
                                      on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                      WHERE p.id != $excludeId -- agrega ésta condición
                                      ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

Comment: se me hace muy complicado tu manera de hacerlo.

Comment: Es lo que se me ocurre con los antecedentes que diste, ahora, si siempre vas a necesitar que la función excluya un id puedes eliminar ese if y agregar directamente el WHERE al sql (tal como la versión anterior de la respuesta, no es necesario excepcionar el id a excluir) ej. .. on u.id_departamento = d.id  WHERE p.id != $excludeId ORDER BY p.nombre ASC ... puedes ver la versión anterior: https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/211016/1